# grant Truncate priviledge on another User in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, database-administration, truncate, sql-grant

I have created below `Oracle` Procedure where i am granting DML priviledges on all tables to `TST` user. Now i also want to grant `Truncate` priviledge to `TST` user in the same Procedure but dont know how to do it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "TBL_MER"."PROCEDURE_GRANT_PRIV"
IS
    BEGIN

    FOR tab IN (SELECT table_name
            FROM   all_tables
            where owner = USER
            order by table_name) LOOP
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON '||tab.table_name||' TO TST';          
      END LOOP;
      COMMIT;
   END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the documentation on the TRUNCATE command?

Quoting from the 19c [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TRUNCATE-TABLE.html#GUID-B76E5846-75B5-4876-98EC-439E15E4D8A4)

> Prerequisites
>
> To truncate a table, the table must be in your schema or you must have
> the DROP ANY TABLE system privilege.

TRUNCATE is not DML.

Comment: i already have this priviledge and yes Truncate is not DML but what i want is to use Truncate also in the same procedure..

Comment: _"but what i want is to use tuncate also in the same procedure"_   I'm not sure what you are asking .. do you want to grant the privilege or do you want to actually truncate a table?  If the latter, why would you want to be doing that - in a procedure that is otherwise only granting privileges?  If the former - you just want to grant the privilege, then add the necessary GRANT statement,  I don't see the difficulty.    But then I wouldn't be using a stored procedure to do what is just a one-off operation.  Just use sql to generate a sql script. Sanity check the resulting script; execute it.

Comment: yes i got it now...can you also please put into answer the one off operation example ...

Comment: Well, I don't know what it is you "got".  I pointed out two conflicting requirements and asked for clarification, which you have not provided. I also pointed out that you only need to add another command to your procedure, depending on which of the two conflicting requirements you need.  Surely you can add a simple GRANT or TRUNCATE command . . . .

Comment: yes i already added another command in procedure and its working now..